# Change ALL Tag Name to Lowercase inside XMLDocument

Tags: c#, xml

I need to change ALL the Tag name to Lowercase but leave the InnerText or Value as it is. I just found the thread showing how to change the casing for the entire document but NOT just for the Tag names.

**Code**

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlDoc.OuterXml.ToLower());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Original.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ROOT>
  <InNeRtAg>SoMe TeXt</InNeRtAg>
  <NeStEdElEmEnT>
    <InNeRnEsTiNg>SoMe TeXt</InNeRnEsTiNg>
  </NeStEdElEmEnT>
</ROOT>
```

Changing **ALL** nodes including the root element:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("Original.xml");

// also need to change the root element
doc.Root.Name = doc.Root.Name.LocalName.ToLower();

foreach (var element in doc.Descendants().Elements())
{
    element.Name = element.Name.LocalName.ToLower();
}

doc.Save("Modified.xml");
```

Results in **Modified.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <innertag>SoMe TeXt</innertag>
  <nestedelement>
    <innernesting>SoMe TeXt</innernesting>
  </nestedelement>
</root>
```

When using

```
foreach (var element in doc.Descendants().Elements())
{
    element.Name = element.Name.LocalName.ToLower();
}
```

the root element will not be changed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ROOT>
  <innertag>SoMe TeXt</innertag>
  <nestedelement>
    <innernesting>SoMe TeXt</innernesting>
  </nestedelement>
</ROOT>
```

Comment: You can use `XDocument.DescendantNodes().OfType<XElement>()` to avoid the special case of RootNode

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(filepath);
foreach (var element in doc.Descendants().Elements())
{
    element.Name = element.Name.LocalName.ToLower();
}
```